# Using Kubectl proxy command to access app directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, proxy, kubectl, amazon-eks

First of all I just want to say that I just recently began working with Kubernetes and I'm sorry in advance if it is a stupid question.

So currently using Kubernetes on AWS EKS. I'm able to access my app from localhost by using the command:

`kubectl proxy --port 9980`

But to access my app, the url is something like:

`127.0.0.1:9980/api/v1/namespaces/NAMESPACE/pods/POD/proxy/MY_API_PATH`

My question is: Is there way to get rid of the `/api/v1/namespaces/NAMESPACE/pods/POD/proxy` and be able to access my app only with : `127.0.0.1:9980/MY_API_PATH`?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for `kubectl port-forward`?  Or a NodePort-type Service?

Comment: @DavidMaze Does port-forward make the app available locally? I'll document myself on that. For the service, I don't want to create new services, I don't think I have the correct permissions.

Comment: You pretty much need to create a Service object matching each Deployment or StatefulSet; communications between Pods use them.  If you have permissions to deploy into the cluster at all you can probably create a Service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidMaze, after documenting myself on the `kubectl port-forward` I found what I was looking for.

Now I understand why I couldn't find a direct answer, it is obvious.

What I did is just:

`kubectl port-forward pods/POD_NAME 9980:8080`